# change state of action buttons on the toolbar in KivyMD

Tags: python, android, kivymd, action-button

I'm trying to write an program for the phone in python using kivy md. The program dynamically adds modules to a page to be counted. I've already got that part sorted in simple kivy.
I'm now trying to replicate it in KivyMD because I can use a navigation drawer and it's screen manager. The program has 2 screens.
Is there way to change the state of the buttons in the action items according to the screen that is active? 
So I'm trying to have 2 overlapped buttons on the right side of the toolbar and show button1 when screen 1 is active and hide button2 and vice-versa.
I used the example from KivyMD documentation on the NavDrawer with the Screen manager and built on that. The left action items is used for the navigation drawer and I am trying to add 2 more buttons on the right side an change their state according to the active screen.
I only managed to add one but I don't know how to add the second one and how to change their state.
Please see below the code I am using:

1. python file

   ```
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView


    class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDScrollView):
        screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
        nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


    class AbacApp(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
            return Builder.load_file('main.kv')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        AbacApp().run()
   ```
2. kv file

   ```
    <ContentNavigationDrawer>

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            MDAnchorLayout:
                anchor_y: "top"
                MDList:
                    TwoLineAvatarListItem:
                        text: "Abacu' lu' Lysu"
                        secondary_text: "Lisandru numara"
                        ImageLeftWidget:
                            source: "img.png"

            MDList:

                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "Module"
                    on_press:
                        root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                        root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "Printare"
                    on_press:
                        root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                        root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


    MDScreen:
        MDBottomAppBar:
            MDTopAppBar:
                pos_hint: {"bottom": 1}
                elevation: 4
                icon: "plus"
                title: "Abacu' lu' Lisandru"
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                on_action_button:
                    id: add_module
                    app.callback()
                on_action_button:
                    id: print_modules
                    app.callback()
                mode: "end"

        MDNavigationLayout:

            MDScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager

                MDScreen:
                    name: "scr 1"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Screen 1"
                        halign: "center"

                MDScreen:
                    name: "scr 2"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Screen 2"
                        halign: "center"


            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)

                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager
                    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
   ```

Comment: Please format yor code with proper indentation.

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation.